# Number of conditional types

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, information-theory

Let $A = \{1, 2, ..., J \}$ and $B = \{1,2, ..., K \}$.

A sequence $x^n \in A^n$ induces a probability distribution $t$ called the *type* where
\begin{align}
   t(j) = \frac{1}{n} |\{x_i:x_i = j \}| \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ for all } j \in A
\end{align}

Two sequences $x^n \in A^n$ and $y^n \in B^n$ induce a joint probability distribution on $A \times B$ called the *joint type* call it $s$ given by
\begin{align}
   s(j, k) &= \frac{1}{n} |\{(x_i, y_i): (x_i, y_i) = (j, k) \}|
\end{align}

We can also define a conditional type of $y^n$ given $x^n$ call it $W$ by
\begin{align}
 W(k|j) &= \frac{s(j, k)}{t(j)}
\end{align}
Let's ignore the case when $t(j) = 0$. It might be irrelevant to the question I want to ask.

The number of types on $A$ is exactly equal to $$\binom{n + J - 1}{J-1}$$

Let's fix $x^n$ of type $t$. What is the number of conditional types $W$ given $x^n$ of type $t$ ? Any lower or upper bounds would help me also .

Answer (score 1):

The question is when $j$ is fixed, how many types $W(\cdot|j)$ are there ? given that there are exactly $nt(j)$ element of $x$ that are equal to $j$ by a dot and bar counting argument similar to what you did, there are exactly $nt(i)+B-1\choose B-1$ such types. So now to compute the total amount of types you just need to multiply all those :
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^J{nt(j)+B-1\choose B-1}
\end{align*}